# Canvas remove background

Tags: canvas, konvajs

How can I remove all background outside the border separating car and the background?

[image: The output image should look like]

Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ecsy6hb4/40/

Comment: can you explain a bit what have you tried... and where are you stuck

Answer (score 2):

At line 39 change: `if (imageData.data[i] > 0) {` with: `if (imageData.data[i] > -1) {`

Explanation: 0 is for black.